# Entity Framework database not showing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

When I select 'add a new item' and then select 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' and select 'Generate from database' in Visual Studio only some databases show up but other databases I have added don't?

Comment: are you sure you are connecting to th correct DB server

Comment: Well one of the databases on the server appears but the other database on the same server does not.

Answer (score 0):

Check the user account with which you're connecting to the database server to verify that it has access to the other databases in question.  If it is your domain account and does not have proper access, you might try changing to SQL server authentication and using a SQL account to connect that has the appropriate privileges (unless you know the DBA and can get permissions added to your domain account).